# Bash - iterate over last number of elements of associative array

Tags: bash

I'm trying to iterate over the last several entries of an associative array in a bash script - in this case to sum up their value. I've tried the following:

```
SUM="0"
for last_element in $(printf "%s\n" "${!ELEMENTS[@]}" | tail -100); do
  ELEMENT_SUM="$(echo "scale=5; $SUM +  ${ELEMENTS[$last_elements]}" | bc)"
done
```

What happens in practice is the the `$last_element` prints out the entire list (of 100 elements in this case), instead of iterating over each - and thus the `${ELEMENTS[$last_elements]}` fails.

I've tried multiple approaches (including negative indexing - `${ELEMENTS[-100]}` for example) with no luck. I'm not sure what it is I'm doing wrong...

Any pointers and ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: "I'm trying to iterate over the last several entries of an *associative* array". *Associative* arrays don't have the concept of "last" and "first"; that's what makes them different from regular arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associative arrays in bash are inherently un-ordered, so there is no concept of a last element or the last 100 elements.

However, if want to sum the values of 100 elements extracted from the array in pseudo-random order, you could do something like this:

```
e100=$(printf "%s\n" "${elements[@]}"  | tail -n 100)
sum=$(echo ${e100//$'\n'/+} | bc)
echo $sum
```

The first line uses `printf` to store 100 elements from associative array `$elements` into variable `$e100`, separated by newline characters.

The second line uses `echo` and bash parameter pattern replacement to change all the newline characters to `+` symbols, which is then piped into `bc` to perform the calculation. The result is stored in variable `$sum`.

BTW, this uses the **values** of the associative array directly, there is no need to iterate over the indexes of the array.

---

There are far better ways of doing this and, as the old joke goes "well, if you wanted to go there, I wouldn't start from here", bash is not a good starting point for any kind of data processing.  Use awk or perl or python or almost anything that isn't shell.

Presumably you're working with floating point numbers and have already realised that bash can only do integer arithmetic, so you're using `bc` to work around that.  You'd be better off using a language that doesn't require you to work around the limitations to do such basic things.

Comment: "Use awk or perl or python or almost anything that isn't shell."  I disagree.  There are many times where getting a script written quickly with a *good enough* straightforward process is more important than invoking a separate interpreter and separate scripts.

Comment: 1. you're making the mistake of assuming that writing a script in awk or perl or python takes longer or is more difficult than writing a script in shell. It isn't. In fact, it can be much easier and faster to write in those languages because you aren't fighting against shell's inadequacies and quirks all the time. 2. I never said anything about separate scripts. That's a shell/bash way of thinking where there's a lot shell can't do, so you need to invoke a bunch of different programs. With other languages, you can do it all in one script using the built-in features and/or specialised libraries

Comment: For example, perl was designed to be the ultimate text-processing and general scripting language, it can do anything that you might otherwise do in bash + sed + awk + tr + grep + cut + many other standard utilities, using syntax which is familiar to users of those tools - all in one language, no need to call any external programs. There's a reason why its often referred to as the "swiss-army chainsaw of scripting languages".   People assume it's hard to learn because bash was hard to learn.  It's not hard, it's actually easier because it doesn't have the programming obstacles that bash has.

Comment: cas, Your solution worked great, thanks! I'm well aware of the limitations of bash for such projects (I usually go with Python), but I was given this task from someone else, who had already written the whole (long) script in bash - so in this case, it's good enough :)

Comment: Perl would be an excellent substitute, but Python has become too much of an OOP language.

Comment: @RonJohn yep, perl is better suited to be a replacement for shell scripting language - it fills that niche much better than python, it was designed to fill the gap between shell and C - but if someone already knows python but doesn't know perl then it's better for them. It can do the job and it's certainly better than shell.  I'd still advise them to learn perl, especially if they're already familiar with sed and awk.

Answer (score 2):

bash associative arrays (for which you need a recent version) don't support arbitrary keys. It also has no operator for sorting lists (which you'd need for that *last* to make sense), and can't do floating point arithmetics.

Here, I'd use a less limited shell like zsh or a proper programming language like perl.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use List::Util "sum";

%elements = (
  "foo"  => 1.213,
  "\0\n" => 0x12,
  ''     => -3,
  "bar"  => 1e-2
  ...
);
$sum = sum(map {$elements{$_}} (sort keys %elements)[-100 .. -1]);
```

```
#! /bin/zsh -

typeset -A elements
elements=(
  foo     1.213
  $'\0\n' 0x12
  ''      -3
  bar     1e-2
  ...
)
set -o extendedglob
sum=$(( ${(@j[ + ])${(@ko)elements}[-100,-1]/(#m)*/$elements[$MATCH]} ))
```

Those give you the sum of the elements for the last 100 keys sorted lexicographically (`memcmp()`-like comparison in perl, `strcoll()`-like in zsh).

For zsh, values may be any arithmetic expression recognised by zsh, but as we're eventually constructing a `value1 + value2 + ...` expression for zsh to evaluate, beware of precedence.

For instance, if `value1` is `var = 3` and `value2` is `4 || hash[$(some-cmd)]`, that ends up evaluating `var = 3 + 4 || hash[$(some-cmd)]` (and `some-cmd` will be executed btw), so you may want to make sure values are surrounded with `(...)` if they're not just numbers.

Comment: [List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util) is very useful.  and included with perl as one of its core libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your great solution, Stéphane!. Unfortunately in this case, I've inherited this script (already written in bash) from someone else, and am thus seeking a simple bash solution. I'll certainly keep this idea in mind for future scripts, though :)